# What is wrong with these PHP scripts in reading JSON?

Tags: php, json

This is the code that I wrote:

```
$result = $textProc->sentiment($text);
$json_a = json_decode($result, true);
echo $json_a[label];
```

where $result stores the JSON data.

However, it returns me error:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp
\htdocs\ai\sentiment.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant label - assumed 'label' in C:\xampp\htdocs
\ai\sentiment.php on line 11
```

Solution:
This is the output of var_dump($result):

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["value"]=> float(0.63882080795918) ["sent"]=> int(1) }
```

Sorry, I should have checked this first.

Comment: How you declare $result?

Comment: Post the output of `var_dump($result);`

Comment: try `var_dump($result)` and see what it returns. You might just be able to cast it to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notice: Use of undefined constant label - assumed 'label' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs \ai\sentiment.php on line 11

On `echo $json_a[label];` label refers to a constant which is not present.

To refer to an element in a associative array, you have do it as following.

```
echo $json_a['label'];
```

---

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   in C:\xampp \htdocs\ai\sentiment.php on line 9

Next, on `$result = $textProc->sentiment($text);`, The function is not returning a string. Do a `var_dump($result)` to ensure, it is returning json **string** format.

Answer (score 1):

$result is NOT a string. Try to find out where in the object the string is stored by using `print_r($result)`.